# Should the same element provide navigation and interaction?

Tags: navigation, drag-n-drop

I have a typical tree navigation with a property window on the right side which configures the selected element.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIfVMI.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Now this elements have to be assigned to another, think appointments to a calendar. My first thought was to have different pages in my app for editing the appointments and adding them to the calendar by Drag & Drop. But this leads to a lot of navigation between these pages especially when the user is changing the content of his appointments during laying them out on the calendar.

I thought about combining navigation and editing by making the elements on the left side Hyperlinks which when clicked upon open their property sheet. Further they would have a designated drag button on hover which slides in the the calendar from the right side when it is clicked.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv12lg.png)</sup>

Is this a feasable approach or will this be too uncommon and confuse the user? Further what if I want to introduce reordering of the element by Drag & Drop? Is adding another Drag & Drop behavior too much? You could for instance go with the double dotted line in front of the items to initiate a drag which then would work in the list and the adjacent calendar.

Is there any UI which does something similar with success?

Comment: I'm not getting it. What is the significance of the calendar WRT the SubItem? What about displaying a clickable calendar in the SubItem edit area; you can highlight already-assigned days in a different color, etc.

Comment: Surely the folder list in the Windows explorer provides both navigation and interaction?

Answer (score 1):

OneNote's Options menu uses something similar to what I think you describe above. Highlighting the entire item to appear as a tile would increase the drag and drop affordance you're looking for while still allowing users to click on the entire button to display the sub-page.

[image]